# How can I solve easy linear equations with minimization problem in R?

Tags: r

I have following Inputs:

```
Inputs <- seq(2,7.7,0.3)
Weights <- paste("w",sep="_",seq(1:20))
```

And the following equations:

```
sum(Weights * Inputs) == 4.8
sum(Weights) == 1 
min(sum(Weights^2))
```

Can someone explain how I get a solution for Weights? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `optim` function. This relies on being able to specify a function that produces a single scalar output which is minimized when the conditions are met. In your case, the function might look like this:

```r
constraints <- function(W) (sum(W * Inputs) - 4.8)^2 + (sum(Weights) - 1)^2
```

So to solve it we can do:

```
Weights <- optim(rep(0.05, 20), constraints, method = "BFGS")$par
```

Which gives us the following result:

```
Weights
#>  [1] 0.04981143 0.04978314 0.04975486 0.04972657 0.04969828 0.04967000 0.04964171
#>  [8] 0.04961343 0.04958514 0.04955685 0.04952857 0.04950028 0.04947200 0.04944371
#> [15] 0.04941543 0.04938714 0.04935885 0.04933057 0.04930228 0.04927400

sum(Weights * Inputs)
#> [1] 4.8

sum(Weights)
#> [1] 0.9908542
```

Obviously, this is a numeric optimization with a 20-dimensional input, so it doesn't perfectly converge to a sum of 1 with the given starting values.